# Arrow vs. Dot in C Structs?

Tags: c, struct

I've got a specific question regarding the arrow vs. dot notation for structs in C. I understand that -> is used for struct pointers, and . is used for objects, however I've been having some trouble parsing some code I found online.

```
    typedef struct node{
        int data;
    }Node;

    typedef struct heap{
        int size;
        Node *dataArray;
    }Heap;

    typedef struct plan{
        int maxPile;
        Heap *heapArray;
    }Plan;
```

Given this code, if I create:

```
    Plan *p
```

And then I want to access a specific index in the heapArray inside Plan I would do:

```
    p->heapArray[i]
```

From here, though if I want to access either the size of the dataArray inside a struct heap, would I use '->' or '.'?

So if I wanted to get the first element of the data array of that heap would I do:

```
    p->heapArray[i].dataArray[0]
```

or

```
    p->heapArray[i]->dataArray[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is

```
p->heapArray[i].dataArray[0]
```

because when you use the subscript on the `heapArray` pointer, it's like doing pointer arithmetic and then dereferencing the pointer, something like this

```
(*(p->heapArray + 1)).dataArray[0]
```

so when you dereference it, the type of it becomes `Heap` which means it's not a pointer and has to be accessed with a `.` and not a `->`.

Answer (score 0):

`p->heapArray[i]` is of type `Heap`, which is a struct, so you'd use `.`.